# Relationship between input variables and principal components in PCA

Tags: r, pca

Here is the result of PCA.
RC1 and RC3 can be interpreted which variables are related.
But, can not interpreted in RC2.
When the eigen value is checked, the number of factor is 3.
But can there really be only two? or Which variables should be related in RC2?

Input variable is 7 types. and I used 'principal()' function.

```
names(mydata)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" 

> x<-cbind(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
> e_value<-eigen(cor(x))
> e_value
eigen() decomposition
$values
[1] 2.3502254 1.4170606 1.2658360 0.8148231 0.5608698 0.3438629 0.2473222

$vectors
           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]         
[,6]         [,7]
[1,]  0.2388621  0.46839043  0.37003850  0.47205027 -0.58802244 
-0.133939151 -0.009233395
[2,]  0.1671739 -0.71097984 -0.14062597  0.25083439 -0.26726985 
-0.502411130 -0.244983436
[3,]  0.2132841 -0.19677142  0.64662974  0.34508779  0.61416969 
-0.003950736  0.036814153
[4,]  0.1697817 -0.24468987  0.55631886 -0.69016805 -0.34039757  
0.039899816  0.089531675
[5,]  0.4857016  0.36681570 -0.09905329 -0.31456085  0.26225761 
-0.344919726 -0.577088755
[6,] -0.5359245  0.20164924  0.17958243 -0.13144417  0.11755661 
-0.748885304  0.218966481
[7,]  0.5635252  0.03619081 -0.27131854 -0.05105919  0.08439733 
-0.219629096  0.741315659


> PCA<-principal(x,nfactors = 3, rotate = "varimax")
> print(PCA)
Principal Components Analysis
Call: principal(r = x, nfactors = 3, rotate = "varimax")
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
           RC1   RC2   RC3   h2   u2 com
A         0.24  0.69  0.29 0.62 0.38 1.6
B         0.25 -0.83  0.24 0.81 0.19 1.3
C         0.06  0.05  0.83 0.69 0.31 1.0
D         0.03 -0.04  0.74 0.54 0.46 1.0
E         0.76  0.42 -0.01 0.76 0.24 1.5
F        -0.83  0.24 -0.17 0.77 0.23 1.3
G         0.92 -0.01  0.00 0.84 0.16 1.0

                       RC1  RC2  RC3
SS loadings           2.23 1.40 1.40
Proportion Var        0.32 0.20 0.20
Cumulative Var        0.32 0.52 0.72
Proportion Explained  0.44 0.28 0.28
Cumulative Proportion 0.44 0.72 1.00

Mean item complexity =  1.3
Test of the hypothesis that 3 components are sufficient.

The root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  0.11 
 with the empirical chi square  63.33  with prob <  1.1e-13 

Fit based upon off diagonal values = 0.84
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! due your question's not strictly about coding, I think it fits better [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between the PCA and 7 variables is right in the output:

```
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
           RC1   RC2   RC3   h2   u2 com
A         0.24  0.69  0.29 0.62 0.38 1.6
B         0.25 -0.83  0.24 0.81 0.19 1.3
C         0.06  0.05  0.83 0.69 0.31 1.0
D         0.03 -0.04  0.74 0.54 0.46 1.0
E         0.76  0.42 -0.01 0.76 0.24 1.5
F        -0.83  0.24 -0.17 0.77 0.23 1.3
G         0.92 -0.01  0.00 0.84 0.16 1.0
```

This matrix is telling you which variables are correlated with THE PCA.  So you can see that `A` and `B` are strongly correlated with principal component 2 (labeled `RC2`).

PCA is a rotation of the data, so there are as many principal components as there are variables (7).  But most people are interested in visualization, so generally only the first 2 or 3 principal components are chosen for plotting.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness answer. but I just know there is a strong correlation between similar numbers like Pearson's correlation. So I think, in my data, in `RC1` , `E` and `G` are strongly correlated, and in `RC3`, `C` and `D` are are strongly correlated.
But as you mentioned in `RC2`, `A` and `B` are strongly correlated. In this cases, am I misinterpreting or misunderstanding PCA results? So what variables are strongly associated in `RC1`, `RC2`, and `RC3`?

Comment: If you're looking for overall association, that would be the `h2` column.  From the package reference: "h2 Communality estimates for each item. These are merely the sum of squared factor loadings for that item."